# Choosing a recaptcha gem for rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, captcha, recaptcha

I am currently working on a rails 3.1 app that is going to be in the wild soon. I need to add captcha's to a couple of the pages (reset password etc). I think I have decided to go with recaptcha's service but I'm stuck trying to decide which gem to use. The two obvious options are:

ambethia / recaptcha: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

and

rack-recapcha https://github.com/achiu/rack-recaptcha

Does anyone have any experience / suggestions as to which works better with rails 3.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm succesfully using ambethia/recaptcha.

The main thing is neither of them are using the asset pipeline from rails 3.1.

Anyhow ambethia/recaptcha. works fine.